# Proposition 5.13 (ii) in Scholze's Perfectoid Spaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, simplicial-stuff, derived-categories, cotangent-complex, perfectoid-spaces

In Proposition 5.13 (ii) in Scholze's [Perfectoid Spaces](https://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/scholze/PerfectoidSpaces.pdf), we have $R \to S$ a morphism of $\Bbb F_p$-algebras and the **assumption** that the relative Frobenius $\Phi_{S/R}$ induces an isomorphism $R_{(\Phi)} \otimes_R^{\Bbb L} S \to S_{(\Phi)}$ in $D(R)$, the derived category of $R$-modules. Here $R_{(\Phi)}$ is the ring $R$ with the $R$-algebra structure given by the Frobenius $R \to R$, and $S_{(\Phi)}$ is similarly defined.

Then they go on to claim, in the proof of (ii), that this **assumption** says that $\Phi_{S^\bullet/R}: R_{(\Phi)} \otimes_R S^\bullet \to S^\bullet_{(\Phi)}$ induces a quasi-isomorphism of simplicial algebras, where $S^\bullet$ is a simplicial resolution of $S$ by free $R$-algebras. I do not understand why. My guess is that this is because the complex $R_{(\Phi)} \otimes_R^{\Bbb L} S \in D(R)$ in the assumption is constructed by taking such a resolution of $S$, so $R_{(\Phi)} \otimes_R^{\Bbb L} S \triangleq R_{(\Phi)} \otimes_R S^\bullet \in D(R)$, and then $S^\bullet_{(\Phi)} \to S_{(\Phi)}$ is a quasi-isomorphism because $S^\bullet_{(\Phi)}$ is a resolution of $S_{(\Phi)}$, so in $D(R)$ we have $R_{(\Phi)} \otimes_R S^\bullet \triangleq R_{(\Phi)} \otimes_R^{\Bbb L} S \cong S_{(\Phi)} \cong S^\bullet_{(\Phi)}$?

After that, they say that this implies that $\Phi_{S^\bullet/R}: R_{(\Phi)} \otimes_R S^\bullet \to S^\bullet_{(\Phi)}$ gives an isomorphism $R_{(\Phi)} \otimes_R^{\Bbb L} \Bbb L_{S/R} \cong \Bbb L_{S_{(\Phi)}/R_{(\Phi)}}$. I also do not understand why. According to the same paper, the complex $\Bbb L_{S/R}$ is defined to be $\Omega^{1}_{S_\bullet/R} \otimes_{S_\bullet} S$, but I do not see a relation. The reference for this part is Lemma 6.5.9 of [Gabber–Romero](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0201175.pdf), which references Proposition II.1.2.6.2 of [Illusie's *Complexe Cotangent et Déformations I*](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540056867), but I do not see how to apply the proposition to this situation.

Finally, both Scholze and Gabber–Romero claim that $\Bbb L_{S_{(\Phi)}/R_{(\Phi)}} \cong \Bbb L_{S/R}$, but I do not know why. I think it is because $R_{(\Phi)}$ is defined to be $R$ as a ring, and the map $R_{(\Phi)} \to S_{(\Phi)}$ as rings should be the same as the map $R \to S$ as rings, so their modules of Kähler differentials should be the same.

P.S. I don't understand why Scholze uses $S_\bullet$ in the definition of $\Bbb L_{S/R}$ when he uses $S^\bullet$. Indeed, Gabber–Romero uses $P^\bullet$ in Lemma 6.5.9.

Comment: do you know that $\Omega_{S\otimes_{R} A/A}=\Omega_{S/R}\otimes A$? and your last statement does not make sense because you say yourself that $R_{(\Phi)} \otimes_R^{\Bbb L} \Bbb L_{S/R} \cong \Bbb L_{S_{(\Phi)}/R_{(\Phi)}}$ unless in your context $R$ is prefect and $R=R_{\Phi}$.

Comment: @ali I've thought more about the last statement and I have edited to add my thoughts.

Comment: @ali Re $\Omega_{S\otimes_{R} A/A}=\Omega_{S/R}\otimes A$: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%A4hler_differential#Examples_and_basic_facts) has a similar fact, but that are for rings; here $S^\bullet$ is a complex, so I don't know if I can still use it.

Comment: module differential of a complex is just obtained by the complex of the module of differentials of each term of that complex. so the fact about rings by definition gives the fact about complexes

Comment: @ali I apologize for the basic question, but is $\otimes_{S^\bullet}$ also defined pointwise?

Comment: first, it is not $\otimes^L$ it is $\otimes$ so yes it is pointwise,in this particular  case $R_\Phi$ and $S$ and hence each free $S$ algebra are Tor independent so there is no difference. also for your last question as you said $S_\Phi,R_\Phi$ as ring are just $R,S$ so obviously $L_{S_\phi/R_\phi}=L_{R/S}$!

Comment: If $\otimes_{S_\bullet}$ is defined pointwise and $\Bbb L_{S/R} = \Omega^1_{S_\bullet/R} \otimes_{S_\bullet} S$ and $S$ is concentrated at degree $0$ then does that mean $\Bbb L_{S/R}$ is concentrated at degree $0$?

Comment: sorry i didn't see the $S\circ$ in your comment I was talking about the case that base is an actual ring. also what do you mean by pointwise?I mean tensor each term with $S$(in general you put $\oplus_{i+j=n}M_i\otimes N_j$ in degree $n$ of $M_\circ\otimes N_\circ$.).in the case of $L_{S/R}$ the last step when you tensor with $S$ over $S_\circ$ does not really change the complex up to an quasi-isomorphism because $S_\circ$ and $S$ are quisi isomorphic to each other.(so you can forget about it)

Comment: if you are comfortable with french in illusie thesis all this things defined and discussed with great details

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Regarding the first and third question, what you say is correct. For the second question, you are looking for the base change compatibility of the cotangent complex: If $R\to R'$ is any map of rings and $S$ is an $R$-algebra such that $S'=S\otimes^L_R R'$ sits in degree $0$, then
$$R'\otimes^L_R \mathbb L_{S/R}\cong \mathbb L_{S'/R'}.$$

To see this, use any simplicial resolution $S_\bullet$ of $S$ by free $R$-algebras; then $S_\bullet\otimes_R R'$ is such a resolution of $S'$. The left-hand side is computed by the simplicial $R'$-module $R'\otimes_R(\Omega^1_{S_\bullet/R}\otimes_{S_\bullet} S)$, and the right-hand side by $\Omega^1_{S'_\bullet/R'}\otimes_{S'_\bullet} S'$; these two simplicial $R'$-modules agree.

Implicit here is that one can use any free resolution to compute the cotangent complex, not necessarily the standard functorial one.

But I think there must be some more basic confusion on cotangent complexes, as you say that you do not see the relation between $\mathbb L_{S/R}$ and $\Omega^1_{S_\bullet/R}\otimes_{S_\bullet} S$. To address this: What do you take as the definition of the cotangent complex?

Comment: $\newcommand{\OSR}{\Omega^1_{S_\bullet/R}}\newcommand{\ot}{\otimes}$Thank you for your answer. I understand that the two simplicial $R'$-modules, $R'\ot_R(\OSR\ot_{S_\bullet}S)$ and $\Omega^1_{S'_\bullet/R'}\ot_{S'_\bullet}S'$, agree. I also accept that $\Bbb L_{S/R}=\OSR\ot_{S_\bullet}S$. What I am confused about is why $R'\ot_R^L\Bbb L_{S/R}=R'\ot_R(\OSR\ot_{S_\bullet}S)$. According to Definition 15.58.15 in [Stacks](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/06XY), one needs a K-flat resolution to compute $\ot_R^L$, and it is not obvious to me why either $R'$ or $\OSR\ot_{S_\bullet}S$ is K-flat.

Comment: You're welcome! For this point, first note that "K-flatness" is only relevant for complexes unbounded to the right, so not here, where flat resolution are good enough. But actually, by the usual formalism of derived functors, acyclic resolutions (for the functor $M\mapsto R'\otimes_R^L M$) are enough, and the given resolution is $R'\otimes_R -$-acyclic, as all terms are free over $S$ and $R'\otimes_R^L S$ sits in degree $0$.